# IDLE's subprocess didn't make connection. Either IDLE can't start a subprocess or personal firewall software is blocking the connection

Tags: python, macos, pygame, osx-elcapitan

I started programing a game on a Mac. Then, I brought the same EXACT code to another Mac.

I got many, many different errors with Pygame saying it wasn't installed, EVEN THOUGH IT WAS!

Anyway, I fixed those errors, then I went to go run the module and the window appeared then it crashed and gave me this message:

> IDLE's subprocess didn't make connection. Either IDLE can't start a
>   subprocess or personal firewall software is blocking the connection

I never got this message before. However, it continues to crash. I have killed idle using the Activity Monitor. There weren't any files in the directory. I have deleted all of the Python files that I have created.

Trashed every `.pyc` file. The Mac I am using is on El Captain; Python is at 2.7.12. Like I said, the code has not changed AT ALL from the first computer.

However, games that are pre-installed with IDLE work perfectly. I have moved the program to the same folders as the games. I copied the content from my program to another file, still nothing.

All help is appreciated, thank you :)

Comment: Try running your script from a elevated command prompt. It may be because you're not the administrator, or your trying to run it on the computers local disk. I was getting the same error when i tried running a python script on my local C:\ drive. The problem was fixed when i moved the script.

Comment: It still crashes. Thanks 4 helping!

Comment: Well just run the script from the elevated the terminal.

Comment: I have no experience with terminals so if you could tell me what to do I would really appreciate it. If not its ok I will figure it out.

Comment: Take your time thanks again for all of the help.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason that your getting this error, is because you're
not the administrator of the computer and you're trying to run a script from your local disk. There are a few things that you could do to solve this.

### 1. Move the .py file:

Before jumping to the method below, simply try moving your python file to a different location on your drive. Then try running the script with the python IDLE. If Your script still won't run, or you must have the script on your local drive, see the second method below

### 2. Run the script from the command prompt\terminal:

To run the script from your command prompt\terminal, first find the path to your python executable. In my case mine is:

> C:\Users[insert user name here]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe

Copy and paste the entire path this into your command prompt\terminal window. Next, find the path to your python file. For an example, the path to my script is:

> C:\test.py

**It is important to note that your path to your python executable cannot contain spaces.**

Next copy and paste the path tot your python file into your command prompt\terminal window. When finished, the command your made should like something like this:

> C:\Users[insert user name here]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe  C:\test.py

Next press enter, and watch your python script run.

Comment: I've tried everything and it still doesn't work. Thank you so much for all your help. I even tested a pygame and it's completely worked. But mine doesn't thanks again for all of the help. I will use your user name as a variable one day 

Comment: I only got the error that is the title. That's it I haven't gotten another one since

Comment: ITS SOMETHING WITH PYGAME!! The program that I found wasn't a pygame it was one that came with idle!!! I tested the pygames all the same crash as my program!!

Comment: (I think it should be too) I deleted all pygame files except my file. Then, I re-installed pygame and still no dice. Could it be something with the computer I'm using?

Comment: I went to the pygame download site. Downloaded the latest iOS version of pygame. Did what it said to do for the installation process. I installed it on the Macintosh HD disk(it was the default place to put it).

Comment: I'm afraid your questions now(how to install Pygame) really are not related to your original question(Python IDLE won't start). in essence you asking how to install Pygame, which is a whole new question, and shouldn't be answered in the comments. Please make a new post for that specific question, so that you can get a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Okie Dokie I figured it out. You have to download the version of idle that is 2.7.(any) IMPORTANT!!! the version has to be 32 bit not 64 bit. Just search on the idle website idle 2.7.12 32 bit. Then download that. Finally download pygame 2.7.

Thanks everyone that helped out!

P.S. Some idle versions didn't work for me. However, 2.7.8 and 2.7.13 did